# Json parse result from virustotal api

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-2010, antivirus

*I was playing around with the virustotal api today while becoming back the result in this form*:

```
{ "permalink" : "http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=7b6b268cbca9d421aabba5f08533d3dcaba50e0f7887b07ef2bd66bf218b35ff-1304089592",
  "report" : [ "2011-04-29 15:06:32",
      { "AVG" : "Exploit_c.TVH",
        "AhnLab-V3" : "PDF/Exploit",
        "AntiVir" : "EXP/Pidief.UK",
        "Antiy-AVL" : "Trojan/win32.agent",
        "Avast" : "JS:Pdfka-gen",
        "Avast5" : "JS:Pdfka-gen",
        "BitDefender" : "Exploit.PDF-JS.Gen",
        "CAT-QuickHeal" : "",
        "ClamAV" : "",
        "Comodo" : "Exploit.JS.Pidief.~AWQ",
        "DrWeb" : "",
        "Emsisoft" : "Exploit.JS.Pdfka!IK",
        "F-Prot" : "",
        "F-Secure" : "Exploit:W32/Pidief.DEE",
        "Fortinet" : "",
        "GData" : "",
        "Ikarus" : "Exploit.JS.Pdfka",
        "Jiangmin" : "",
        "K7AntiVirus" : "",
        "Kaspersky" : "Exploit.JS.Pdfka.dnc",
        "McAfee" : "",
        "McAfee-GW-Edition" : "",
        "Microsoft" : "Exploit:Win32/Pdfjsc.NJ",
        "NOD32" : "PDF/Exploit.Pidief.PGD",
        "Norman" : "",
        "PCTools" : "Trojan.Pidief",
        "Panda" : "",
        "Prevx" : "",
        "Rising" : "",
        "SUPERAntiSpyware" : "",
        "Sophos" : "Troj/PDFJs-RD",
        "Symantec" : "Trojan.Pidief",
        "TheHacker" : "",
        "TrendMicro" : "TROJ_PIDIEF.VTG",
        "TrendMicro-HouseCall" : "TROJ_PIDIEF.VTG",
        "VBA32" : "",
        "VIPRE" : "Exploit.PDF-JS.Gen (v)",
        "ViRobot" : "PDF.S.Exploit.74634",
        "VirusBuster" : "",
        "eSafe" : "",
        "eTrust-Vet" : ""
      }
    ],
  "result" : 1
}
```

**I would like to know how one can parse this result to fill a memo like:**

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Antivirus: %0s Result: %1s', [...]));
```

Well, I really have no clue about all the JSon components which might be around to maybe someone can direct me to the right direction here?

Kindest regards,

H.Meiser

Comment: which version of delphi are you using?

Comment: This doesn't require JSON or anything else. It's extremely simple text-parsing, which can be handled with a couple of calls to `Pos` to extract the pertinent text (the part between `[]`), a `TStringList` using `CommaText` and `StrictDelimiters`, and a very simple loop to separate the two halves of each line (the AV name and the output). Why would you want to add the complexity of an external library for such a simple job?

Comment: Well, for example while the result (Json) I've got might be changed in future so it might be variable? At least nothing wrong learning how to parse it with json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing  Json string is not difficult, you can use the [`DBXJSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBXJSON) unit included since delphi 2010.

check this sample code

```
Uses
  DBXJSON;

procedure TForm1.ParseString(const AString: string);
var
  json          : TJSONObject;
  jPair         : TJSONPair;
  jValue        : TJSONValue;
  jcValue       : TJSONValue;
  l,i           : Integer;
begin
    json    := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AString),0) as TJSONObject;
  try
    //get the pair to evaluate in this case the index is 1
    jPair   := json.Get(1);
    //cast the JsonValue to TJSONArray to access the elements of the array
    jValue := TJSONArray(jPair.JsonValue).Get(1);
    l:=TJSONArray(jValue).Size;
    for i:=0 to l-1 do
    begin
     //get the i element of the array 
     jcValue := TJSONArray(jValue).Get(i);
     //get the pair pointing to the i element 
     jPair   := TJSONPair(jcValue);
     //show the result 
     Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Antivirus %s Result %s',[jPair.JsonString.Value,jPair.JsonValue.Value]));
    end;
  finally
     json.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As additional recommendation you must read a Json tutorial to learn how interpret the Json format and in this way you must be preparated to use any library available.

Comment: I Agree with you reading about json. I have tested your procedure but it gaves me an access violation?

Comment: i tested the code with the same string which you post. in which line do you have problems?

Comment: Well the access violation is raised directly while calling ParseString? ParseString(Memo2.Text); boom

Comment: Strange same result the access violationn raised on this line:jValue := TJSONArray(jPair.JsonValue).Get(1);

Comment: I compiled the code using Delphi-XE (I don't have Delphi 2010), the only idea which i have is a change between versions in the `DBXJSON` unit are using the same string which you post it?

Comment: Additionally you can check this link http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/category/json/ which show another ways to parse a json response from delphi, the sample articles uses the google trasnlate api response, but you can adapt the code to fit with you requirement.

Comment: You are right RRUZ after checking your source in XE everything works as exspected so in 2010 something must be different!

Comment: @HMeiser: Yeah, there were a handful of fixes in `dbxjson` between D2010 and XE.

Comment: @HMeiser, JSON parser as in D2010 is not compliant to JSON specs. It violates at least two clauses: [insignificant whitespace](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2), [exponential notation](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2.4). Do not use it.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend the open source JSON library [SuperObject](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6) and online JSON inspectors like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ or http://json.parser.online.fr/ (this editor has a very useful option which adds type information to the view)

Comment: Both those JavaScript application are not useful at all. JSON is specially designed to be human-friendly.