# Delphi JSON library for XE2 available for object serialization

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe2

There appears to be a few JSON options for Delphi out there - is there a recommended library for use with XE2?  I'm looking for sharing of objects between Delphi XE2 and PHP web applications.  (serialization and posting delphi objects in a compatible way for PHP web apps and de-serialization from a restful PHP call to delphi server side)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know of two libraries.

The built in library and [Super Object](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject).

I use Super Object as it's really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks - have you tried it with XE2?

Answer (score 11):

JSON support* is included in XE2 (and XE). [JSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON)

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431670/delphi-serverside-framework-for-managing-sessions-and-respond-with-json-to-ajax-r) in SO for a link to a paper by Marco, explaining use of JSON and restful implementations.

[REST Servers in Delphi XE
Using DataSnap](http://app.en25.com/e/er.aspx?s=608&lid=4414&elq=d428643420d2494581299418d9753feb)

- Note : This is valid for the Enterprise and up version.

Comment: D2010 has DBXJSON included too, but it is severely broken (see [note](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217595/json-parse-result-from-virustotal-api/6218635#6218635))

Answer (score 5):

- [SuperObject](http://code.google.com/p/superobject/)
- [lkJSON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/)

Unlike XML libraries (OmniXML, NativeXml) lkJSON does not provide methods to serialize TObject / TPersistent instances using RTTI directly, it requires custom code to map the property values to a JSON object.

SuperObject support marshaling for Delphi 2010 and higher.

Comment: You can serialize with SuperObject

Answer (score 5):

[DWScript](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/) has a dwsJSON unit which implements a fast JSON parser & writer, it doesn't rely on RTTI/TPersistent but on mapping by custom code.

Answer (score 2):

Open source [delphi-oop](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-oop/) library includes powerful serializer. It can use multiple backends (including native DBXJSON, superobject, NativeXml) and can serialize/deserialize almost anything. Some more information available in the project's [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-oop/wiki/SvSerializer)

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, there is one more JSON library, compatible with Delphi7+ and FPC.

It is side-project of mORMot and is speed-optimized (there were comparisons with SuperObject, though i don't recall the link)

- http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/06/02/Fast-JSON-parsing
- http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI
- http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/05/03/Custom-JSON-serialization-of-records
- http://blog.synopse.info/tag/JSON