# GeoJSON open source library

Tags: delphi, open-source, geojson

I have made an extensive search on the net but were still in vain.

I am looking for an open source GeoJSON library.

Help me please.

**Last update:**

My preference goes for something build on top of [SuperObject](http://code.google.com/p/superobject/) library.

- [GeoJSON specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html).

Comment: Stop closing all questions already. It's starting to become really annoying to have questions half-answered because of the trigger-happy delphi closing-team. Just downvote if you don't like it, or write a comment to explain how the question could be improved.

Comment: In this case, I agree, but as a regular close voter (most often for vague and completely unanswerable questions) I believe it is an essential part of what keeps Stackoverflow from devolving into a discussion forum. Looking for open source component or library for X is essentially ON TOPIC, and "google it" is not always the best way to find it. In fact, reverse is true.  It seems lately that such questions get top linked to stackoverflow  within 5 minutes of asking them, so such questions are welcome here. +1 menjaraz.

Comment: @warren p: Thanks for your explanation. Menjaraz, sorry for hijacking your question with this meta discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using SuperObject to parse (geojson) results that i pull from GeoServer.

GeoJson is not that complicated so i don't think it matters much which library you use.

Comment: Absolutely. The JSON library (SuperObject) is in fact, the only thing you should need. The rest of invoking any REST/JSON webapi ought to be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is none.

But you can easily retrieve and create a GeoJSON content with a JSON library. GeoJSON content is just a tree of JSON objects.

Recent versions of Delphi have a built-in JSON parser.

Or take a look at [Delphi JSON library for XE2 available for object serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731833/delphi-json-library-for-xe2-available-for-object-serialization) to find out some libraries. I like the one embedded in DWScript.