# Does anyone have an example of round trip serialization of JSON in Delphi XE6?

Tags: json, delphi, serialization, delphi-xe6

I want to code a (what I would think is a simple) round trip serialization of an object in Delphi.  But, I can't seem to figure out how to do it to/from JSON.  I can, and have for some time, do it with XML.

However, the example and explanation I've found in the standard Embarcadero docs, e.g. local help, DocWiki, etc. haven't helped me much.

**Preferably**, I am looking for an actual working example **using XE(6) native libraries or components** -- ***but***, I would be grateful for links to any writeups (docs, articles, posts, etc..) and/or ***any other libraries*** that anyone has used to get this working.

Comment: Suggested reading, [Serializing User Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Serializing_User_Objects). Should answer your question, using Delphi [JSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON) library. For other alternatives, see [Delphi JSON library for XE2 available for object serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731833/delphi-json-library-for-xe2-available-for-object-serialization?rq=1).

Comment: Yeah... I've already checked that out. tx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using the native framework, the main reason being that it serializes private members of objects, which I think breaks OOP encapsulation principles. It would be more correct imho to serialize the published properties of classes. It breaks interoperability with other languages.

Anyway, here is a basic example.

```
implementation

uses
  Serializable,
  REST.JsonReflect,
  System.Json,
  System.SysUtils;


{ TMain }

procedure TMain.Run;
var
  mySerializable: TMySerializable;
  marshaller: TJSONMarshal;
  unMarshaller: TJSONUnMarshal;
  jsonValue: TJSONValue;
begin
  mySerializable := TMySerializable.Create;
  mySerializable.MyInt := 42;
  mySerializable.MyString := 'The Answer';
  // Serialize
  marshaller := TJSONMarshal.Create;
  jsonValue := marshaller.Marshal(mySerializable);
  marshaller.Free;
  mySerializable.Free;
  mySerializable := nil;
  WriteLn('JSon value:');
  WriteLn(jsonValue.ToString);
  // Deserialize
  unMarshaller := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
  mySerializable := TMySerializable(unMarshaller.CreateObject(TMySerializable, TJSONObject(jsonValue)));
  WriteLn('mySerializable.MyInt: ' + IntToStr(mySerializable.MyInt));
  WriteLn('mySerializable.MyString: ' + mySerializable.MyString);

  jsonValue.Free;
  mySerializable.Free;
  unMarshaller.Free;
  ReadLn;

end;
```

And the unit Serializable defines a simple test class.

```
unit Serializable;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TMySerializable = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FMyString: string;
    FMyInt: Integer;
  published
    property MyInt: Integer read FMyInt write FMyInt;
    property MyString: string read FMyString write FMyString;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Access control is a compile-time feature. All fields may be relevant and required to carry the object state. Java and other languages use annotations to indicate which fields should (not) be serialized.